# FragmentStateAdapter crashes, throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-viewpager, androidx, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

In my app, I have a `PlaylistMenuFragment` with a button that replaces itself in the `ViewPager` with `PlaylistContentFragment`, and vice-versa, through the following methods:

```
fun goToPlaylistContent() {
    pagerAdapter.replaceLastFragmentWith(PlaylistContentFragment())
}

fun goToPlaylistMenu() {
    pagerAdapter.replaceLastFragmentWith(PlaylistMenuFragment())
}
```

The adapter method that is being called:

```
fun replaceLastFragmentWith(newFragment: Fragment) {
    fragmentList[LAST_FRAGMENT_INDEX] = newFragment
    notifyItemChanged(LAST_FRAGMENT_INDEX)
}
```

If I click a button inside `PlaylistMenuFragment` that goes to `PlaylistContentFragment`, executing the methods above, everything works fine. But if then I click a button inside `PlaylistContentFragment` that goes back to `PlaylistMenuFragment`, the app crashes, throwing the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2$RecyclerViewImpl{8ebfd7a VFED..... ......ID 0,0-720,1040 #1}, adapter:com.pegoraro.musicast.main.PagerAdapter@a12492b, layout:androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2$LinearLayoutManagerImpl@e567188, context:com.pegoraro.musicast.main.MainActivity@e8e6424
```

The crash traces back to the methods above. If I wrap the *notifyItemChanged* inside the adapter method with a try-catch block, the app works as intended, with no sign of problem, unless I look in the logcat, which still shows the exception being thrown. It is a dirty fix, which I don't like:

```
fun replaceLastFragmentWith(newFragment: Fragment) {
    fragmentList[LAST_FRAGMENT_INDEX] = newFragment
    try {
        notifyItemChanged(LAST_FRAGMENT_INDEX)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("TEST", e.toString())
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement a sort of navigation between these two Fragments inside a `TabLayout`, and this is the way I managed to do. So if the error comes from a fundamental problem of how I am approaching this issue, what is an alternative? And if not, what could be the cause of the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling any of `notifyXX()` methods on the `ViewPager2` adapter is the same as that of the `RecyclerView`, because `ViewPager2` internally functions based on RecyclerView.

And since `notifyXX()` methods work in background thread, and in your case this directly affects one of the ViewPager current fragments; so you need to explicitly do this in UI thread

```
viewpager.post {
    notifyItemChanged(LAST_FRAGMENT_INDEX)
}
```